# Discord.py Hug command with image

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a hug command that sends an image. But upon sending the command, nothing happens. No error in the cli and no message in the channel.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def hug(ctx):

    os.chdir(r"file to the folder holding the images")

    hugs = [discord.File('1.jpg'), discord.File('2.jpg'), discord.File('3.jpg'), discord.File('4.gif'), discord.File('5.gif'), discord.File('6'), discord.File('7.gif'), discord.File('8.gif'), discord.File('9.gif'), discord.File('10.gif'), discord.File('11.gif')]
    hugsrandom = random.choise(hugs)

    await ctx.send(file=hugsrandom)
```

I also tried just sending an image inside the folder with the bot file and took out `os.chdir` but still nothing sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE2: The following just worked for me... I would almost certainly expect your issue is that your files are not being created properly.  Either that or your bot is broken in some other way.  If you use a debugger (say pycharms) you could set break points and see if your command is executing and whether or not your discord.File objects are being created properly

```
    async def test(self, ctx):
        image = r"C:\Users\name\Desktop\visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg"
        import discord
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(image))
```

UPDATE: I did not read far enough, it should accept a string path.  Have you tried debugging into the code to see if it's successful at opening your file?

Sometimes it's worth looking at the source code.  I went and looked at discord.File.

```
class File:
    """A parameter object used for :meth:`abc.Messageable.send`
    for sending file objects.

    Attributes
    -----------
    fp: Union[:class:`str`, :class:`io.BufferedIOBase`]
        A file-like object opened in binary mode and read mode
        or a filename representing a file in the hard drive to
        open.

        .. note::

            If the file-like object passed is opened via ``open`` then the
            modes 'rb' should be used.

            To pass binary data, consider usage of ``io.BytesIO``.
    """
    def __init__(self, fp, filename=None, *, spoiler=False):
        self.fp = fp

        if isinstance(fp, io.IOBase):
            if not (fp.seekable() and fp.readable()):
                raise ValueError('File buffer {!r} must be seekable and readable'.format(fp))
            self.fp = fp
            self._original_pos = fp.tell()
            self._owner = False
        else:
            self.fp = open(fp, 'rb')
            self._original_pos = 0
            self._owner = True
```

It appears as though it's expecting an opened file.

Comment: I tried sending an image from the examples [here:] (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-image) but it didn't even send the image in the same file pather. I can try to have it send a message to see if it is able to send a message.

Comment: have you tried using a debugger and seeing if your discord.File object is properly being created?  A properly created discord.File object should have the function read(), which should return the contents of the file.

Comment: for what it's worth I just did it

Comment: Honestly, I thought it would just send the image. After reading deeper into the docs I saw an example with this code and realized it creates a file.
```python
with open('bb8aed07d6c27ef0e96567d62699900a.jpg', 'rb') as fp:
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp, 'test.jpg'))
```
I tried it with the bot file and image file in the same folder and still nothing. All the debugging I did was moving stuff around. Tbh I've never done serious debugging before.

Comment: I would STRONGLY recommend learning some basic debugging techniques.  Pycharm can be a bit intimidating at first, but the debugger is awesome.  You could set a breakpoint on hugsrandom line, and just look at the object.  What is it?  is it broken?  you can event test running instructions with the "evaluation expression" alt-f8... so you could call hugsrandom.read() and see what it returns.  These are very valuable skills to have if you want to write code.

Comment: Thank you!! You helped more than just telling me my error^^

Comment: of course, I wouldn't accept my answer, because it's not a great answer (or really an answer at all?), but feel free to upvote it so I can at least get a little reputation :)  If you start doing some debugging I might be able to come up with an actual answer for you, at this point it's hard to tell what is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219298/discussion-between-bravosierra99-and-unknown-shell).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to do `os.chdir()`.
It can have unintended consequences. Instead do:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(__file__)
PICTURE_1_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../pictures/1.jpg')
PICTURE_1_FILE = discord.File(PICTURE_1_PATH)
```

`BASE_DIR` is the path of folder containing the python file.
`../pictures/1.jpg` is the relative path to that folder.

Comment: But I would have to define every single image cuz I have 20+ images/gifs so defining all pictures would be too much to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan all the files paths in the folder and add them to the list using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

```py
import glob

hugs = glob.glob("FULL_PATH_HERE/*") # this wil get all the file paths in the foldes.
# ['FULL_PATH_HERE/1.gif', 'FULL_PATH_HERE/2.jpg']
the_hug = random.choice(hugs)

ctx.send(file = discord.File(the_hug))
```

Comment: So like this?

`hugs = glob.glob("Path\Path") ['image.jpg', 'image.jpg', 'image.jpg', 'image.jpg']`

Answer (score 0):

```py
hug_gifs = ["","","","","","", "", ""] #Put the hug gifs you would like to use
hug_names = ['', '', ''] #Put the hug names you would like to use


@client.command()
async def hug(ctx, *, member : discord.Member):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour=discord.Colour(0xCE3011),
            description=f"{ctx.author.mention} {(random.choice(cuddle_names))} {member.mention}"

        )
        embed.set_image(url=(random.choice(cuddle_gifs)))

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

#Not images but gifs are better
```